# Call Variable from a function to another function within PHP class

Tags: php, class

i use this class below i want use the variables array or property array ($g_types) in first_function how i can do this?

```
class My_Class {
    function first_function() {
        //HOW I CAN USE THE $g_types array Variable values in this function?
    }
    function second_function() {
        $g_types = array(
            'Person Widget'    => 'g_person',
            'Page Widget'      => 'g_page',
            'Community Widget' => 'g_community'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: `$this->g_types = ...` PHP OOP 101

Comment: thank you but i used the $g_type property in it own function how i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to archive this, is by using a class-variable.

```
class My_Class {
    private $g_types;
    function first_function() {
        $gperson = $this->g_types['g_person'];
    }
    function second_function() {
        $this->g_types = array(
            'Person Widget'    => 'g_person',
            'Page Widget'      => 'g_page',
            'Community Widget' => 'g_community'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can return $g_types in second function and use it in first function.

```
function first_function()
{
$returnedValue = second_function();
}
```

But i suggest you to read about scope of the variables in php so that you won't encounter this problem anymore.